# datetimepicker getElementById vs name ie8 issues

Tags: php

I have a javascript datetimepicker that works well with everything except IE7 or above.  The issue seems to be with `getElementById`.  Here is how current code looks:

```
<tr>
 <td style="width: 143px">Call Date:
 </td>
<td style="width: 472px">
<input type="Text" name=cdate size=40 style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;">
<a href="javascript:NewCal('cdate','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

In IE7 or above this will not work. I get "Javascript error object missing".  If I change `name=cdate` to `id=cdate` it works but but when I submit the form to my php insert:

```
<?
$cdate=$_POST['cdate'];
```

The submission fails. So how can I correct this or how can I make the `id= element` be by `name= element` ....hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `name` and `id` so server will get the name and you can use `id` on the client side

```
<input type="Text" name="cdate" id="cdate" size="40" style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66; width: 270px;" />
```

So you can use on the server side

```
$cdate=$_POST['cdate']; // because it has name="cdate"
```

and on the ckient side you can use

```
var cdate=getElementById('cdate'); // Because it has id="cdate"
```

Comment: Worked, thanks so much, I feel like a total idiot, solution so simple.

Comment: Welcome! We make mistakes because we are human not because we are idiot. :-)

Comment: Worked well, until I tried it with Firefox, when I use firefox I get Notice: Undefined index: cdate in d:\web\apache\htdocs\callz\callz_insert_record.php on line 4
Record added  ......  this is the submit form , the line  $cdate=$_POST['cdate'];    If I remove the id=cdate the error disappears but of course the datepicker will not work.  Any idea?